# Gitlab in Docker: postgresql not accepting connection

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I'm trying to create a very simple Gitlab instance with docker. I have this docker-compose.yml file (mostly straight out of the documentation) :

```
gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    restart: always
    hostname: gitlab.${DOMAIN}
    ports:
        - 8081:8081
    environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=gitlab.${DOMAIN}
        - VIRTUAL_PORT=8081
    volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH}/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
        - ${DATA_PATH}/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
        - ${DATA_PATH}/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
```

The problem is that whenever i try to up this image, i get an error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I'm running Docker for Mac 18.06.1-ce, on OSX 10.13.6

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: The message indicates that something is trying to access Postgres via a Unix socket. If you get this error, I assume that Gitlab needs a Postgres database to run, which is not provided in the gitlab-ce image. So you will have to mount your host Postgres socket as a volume for your `gitlab` service. Or you could add a `postgres` service to your docker-compose.yml and share its postgres socket with the gitlab service (or configure them to communicate via tcp)

Comment: postgres is installed by default in the gitlab-ce image, according to its Dockerfile

Comment: I'm looking at the differences between your docker-compose file and [the one in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose) and I can see you are missing the `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG` environment variable.

Comment: Yes this will probably solve another problem later. In the meantime, i fixed my issue, see my answer if you're curious...

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed it. Turns out macOS has (apparently ?) a limit on the length of a path. And my docker image exceeded this limit....